# jquery ajax - how do I use the "done" callback?

Tags: ajax, jquery

According to the jquery ajax documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, there are 5 "callback queues" which are beforeSend, error, dataFilter, success and complete.

However all the examples use .done() which doesn't seem to be documented at all.

Is "done" something other than a callback queue? where is it documented? what's the difference between .done() and .complete()? which should I be using?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ is where's the documentation at.

Comment: _Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead._

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I fear jQuery is getting a bit like php - there are far too many ways to to the same thing :(